# Compiler warning - suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value

Tags: c, compiler-construction, compiler-warnings

When I try to compile the piece of code below, I get this warning:

`warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value`

Why does this happen? This is a rather common idiom, I believe. I even use something like it earlier on my code.

```
struct PIDList* 
getRecordForPID(struct PIDList* list, pid_t pid) {
    while(list = list->next)
        if (list->pid == pid)
            return list;

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: You're free to turn off the warning, or rather leave it off since it's off by default...

Comment: I'm sort of absent minded so I am thankful for pedantic, -Wall, -Wextra, -Wshadow and the like

Comment: Well you can add `-Wno-parentheses` (I believe that's the right one) to disable this specific warning. However, if you're that absent-minded, be careful not to write `=` instead of `==`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [warning: suggest parentheses around assignment while (\*(arg\_to++) = \*(arg\_from++));](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48334266/warning-suggest-parentheses-around-assignment-while-arg-to-arg-from)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Be explicit - then the compiler won't warn that you perhaps made a mistake.

```
while ( (list = list->next) != NULL )
```

or

```
while ( (list = list->next) )
```

Some day you'll be glad the compiler told you, people *do* make that mistake ;)

Comment: People do! For this very reason, I used to write `if (0 == varName)` in C, so that I could get an error message if I mistyped it.

Comment: @jpaugh That is called a Yoda condition. It has a Wikipedia page :)

Comment: @LarsNyström Pleased I am to know this!

Answer (score 66):

While that particular idiom is common, even more common is for people to use `=` when they mean `==`.  The convention when you really mean the `=` is to use an extra layer of parentheses:

```
while ((list = list->next)) { // yes, it's an assignment
```

Answer (score 24):

It's just a 'safety' warning.  It is a relatively common idiom, but also a relatively common error when you meant to have `==` in there. You can make the warning go away by adding another set of parentheses:

```
while ((list = list->next))
```