# If m % n == k or m % n == l then print 1, else print any other number

Tags: c++, modulo

4 integers are given (all no more than 10^6): m, n, k, l. If m % n == k or m % n == l, then print 1, else any other number. Conditional operators cannot be used!

Examples:

```
12 8 3 4 // input
1 // output

0 5 1 2 // input
0 // output
```

I wrote this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int m, n, k, l;
cin >> m >> n >> k >> l;

cout << ((1 / (((m % (n + 1 / (n + 1))) - k) * ((m % (n + 1 / (n + 1))) - k) + 1)) - 1) * ((1 / (((m % (n + 1 / (n + 1))) - l) * ((m % (n + 1 / (n + 1))) - l) + 1)) - 1) + 1;

return 0;
}
```

But it does not work for all cases. For example, 0, 0, 0, 0 gives 1, but should give any other number.
Please help.

Comment: The requirement is unclear. The conditional operator is `?:`. Do you perhaps actually mean boolean operators like `and` and `or` ?

Comment: Is this code for an obfuscation challenge?

Comment: 0%0 (or anything `%0`) is mathematically undefined, because Modulo implies a division, meaning you actually 'divide by zero' with these parameters. With integers, your program should crash, with floating point numbers, you should get 'Infinity' (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51474239/c-warning-division-of-double-by-zero).

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is no answer for `n == 0` because division by zero is undefined.

In the other cases, since `true` prints as "1" and `false` as "0" by default,

```
cout << (m % n == l || m % n == k);
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

what i understand from your question you are checking for 2 conditions, so after taking the input from the user we can check those conditions and assign value of val integer to 1 if that condition is true, else it will be 0 as initialized.

```
int m, n, k, l;
int val =0;
cin >> m >> n >> k >> l;

if(m % n == k || m % n == l){
 val = 1;
}
cout << val ;
```

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand I think you are trying to compare the modulus of two numbers with the other two inputs and if the result matches you want 1 as output otherwise 0

this will help you achieve it

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int m, n, k, l;
cin >> m >> n >> k >> l;

if(m%n == k || m%n == l)
{
  count << 1
}
else 
{ 
  count << 0
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Besides the requirements that "[c]onditional operators cannot be used!" likely also applies to `if` statements, code-only answers are highly discouraged as they tend to promote [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), which is bad. You also don't really tell the OP what was wrong with the code in the question, or how your code would solve that problem. Please read about [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).