# Does a copied string end with a '\0' (Section 1.9 The C Programming Language K&R2)

Tags: c

In the last line of  **copy function** I have stored a **'\0'** at the end of the copied string, this was not originally in the code.

```
include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000               /* maximum input line size */

int getline(char line[ ], int maxline);    
void copy(char to[ ], char from[ ]);

/* print longest input line*/
int main()
{
    int len;                   /* current line length */
    int max;                  /* maximum length seen so far */
    char line[MAXLINE];      /*current input line*/
    char longest[MAXLINE];  /* longest line saved here */

    max=0;
    while ((len=getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)     
        if (len > max)
        {
            max=len;
            copy(longest, line); 
        }
    if (max>0)         /* there was a line*/
        printf("%s", longest);
    return 0;
}

/* getline: read a line into s, return length */
int getline(char s[ ], int lim)
{            
    int c,i;
    for(i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i]=c;
    if(c=='\n')
    {
        s[i]=c;
        ++i;
    }
   s[i]='\0';
   return i;
}

/* copy: copy 'from' into 'to'; assume to is big enough */
void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;
    i=0;
    while((to[i]=from[i])!='\0')
        ++i;
    to[i] = '\0';      /*<-----Problematic Area*/
}
```

My question here is, whether the *copied string already contains a '\0'* at the end. If it is not so then is it a good practice to include it as I have done in the code.

Comment: strcpy copies up to and including the terminator...

Comment: In your `copy` function the `while` loop writes a `NUL` character to `to[i]` before checking to see if it's a `NUL` character.  `to[i] = '\0` is thus redundant.

Comment: If program logic is too convoluted to follow mentally, use a debugger to see what's going on.

Comment: Oh!! I totally missed it @Fiddling Bits.....thanks I think I got my answer.

Comment: Fyi, `copy` can be trimmed to just: `while ((*to++ = *from++));` It's not like you need those pointers for anything later anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement

```
while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
    ++i;
```

first assigns the value of `from[i]` to `to[i]` and *then* compares the assigned value to `\0` - if it was the null terminator that was just copied, the loop ends.

Thus

```
to[i] = '\0';
```

is unnecessary, but not otherwise incorrect here.

However, having unnecessary code around is not good style because it makes refactoring and reasoning about the other code *harder*. Just the presence of that last assignment could then confuse a future reader into thinking that the loop in itself is not sufficient to properly terminate the string.

Additionally, should someone come and edit the code into

```
while ((*to++ = *from++));
```

as suggested by WhozCraig, they could then mistakenly think that they *do* need to add the null terminator, this time potentially writing out of bounds:

```
*to++ = 0;
```

Comment: why double parentheses on `while ((*to++ = *from++));` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre [suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476759/compiler-warning-suggest-parentheses-around-assignment-used-as-truth-value)