# getchar/putchar returns boxes with question marks when printing inputted characters

Tags: c, character-encoding, codeblocks

Playing around with code examples from K&R in Codeblocks on Windows 10 (Danish language). The following example works as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c = 'a';
    putchar(c);
}
```

However, the following prints a series of boxes with question marks, the same number as the number of characters I type:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c;

    while (c = getchar() != '\n') {
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

So it looks like an encoding issue. When run, a command prompt opens with "C:\Users\username\Desktop\filename.exe" in the header, and my username contains the Danish character "å" which is replaced by a "Õ". The command prompt uses the CP 850 character set.

(By the way, I'm not checking if the character equals `EOF`, since that produces odd results. Pressing enter prints the expected number of boxes, plus one for `\n`, but it doesn't end the program.)

Comment: The [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an ***`int`***. This is important if you ever what to check for `EOF` (which you really should do even for input from `stdin`).

Comment: I don't know why your output is strange, but `EOF` is of type `int`, and `getchar` returns `int` not `char`. Stupid function name? Very much so. Which is why bothering with all the old stdio.h crap in K&R is mostly a waste of time. Nobody writes console programs since 20 years back.

Comment: And what is the ouput of ypur program if the input is `ABC`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are seeing a problem of operator precedence here. As you can see on [this chart](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators_precedence.htm), `=` has a lower precedence than `!=`.

This means that `getchar() != '\n'` is evaluated first.

To the compiler your code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c;

    while (c = (getchar() != '\n')) { 
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

Since 'c' is getting an incorrect value (the true/false evaluation of the expression), the output is incorrect, and the program gives the behavior you are seeing, however

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') { //<----notice brackets around c=getchar 
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

gives the output you are expecting. This illustrates the fact that you should always put brackets around such expressions to be safe.

Comment: Of course, don't know how I missed that. Thank you, it works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

This line is bad.

```
while (c = getchar() != '\n')
```

It should be:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')
```

Comment: Alltough correct, I feel this is a bit of a minimal answer. Any explanation why the one is bad and the other is good would suite this answer well.

Answer (score 2):

There are already some correct answers within the scope of the question but there are a couple of wider problems that you need to address.

Firstly `getchar()` returns an `int` and it is important that you define the variable that takes the return value as an `int` so you can differentiate errors and end of file from valid `char`s.

Secondly, if you receive end of file or there is an error on `stdin` before the program encounters a `\n`, your code will loop forever. This is what the man page on my laptop says about `getchar()`

> If successful, these routines return the next requested object from the stream. Character values are returned as an unsigned char converted to an int.  If the stream is at end-of-file or a read error occurs, the routines return EOF.

So once getchar() returns `EOF` it will return `EOF` all the time. You need to address this in your loop condition:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int c;    // c declared as int

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')) 
    { 
        putchar(c);
    }
    if (c == EOF) 
    {
        // handle errors and end of file as you see fit
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, in unix at least, if you `getchar()` from a tty, it returns `EOF` only on two consecutive (without any other character in between) `Ctrl-D` characters (or if `Ctrl-D` is the first character in the stream of data read by the program, or on a `\n` followed by a `Ctrl-D`).   But if you call it again, you can continue reading input without any problem.   `EOF` is returned only on such condition (or several others, like invalidating the tty device)

Comment: @LuisColorado Nope. The man page for getchar on my Mac says: "The end-of-file condition is remembered, even on a terminal, and all subsequent attempts to read will return EOF until the condition is cleared with clearerr(3)."

Comment: @LuisColorado and I was sad enough to write a program to test it.

Comment: It's possible different implementations do different things... but I have tested in some unices... Solaris, unix v7, Linux Debian (but i guess all linuxes do) behave as I told.  All BSDs I've tested (OpenBSD, FreeBSD and NetBSD, and Mac OSX --- I've not tested this last one, but you say and it's a derived work from FreeBSD, so I trust you) behave as you say.  I think is the implementation of the stdio package that makes the difference.  I have no System III or System V unix to test, but from v7 & Solaris, I guess they will do as at&t unix.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** You get the boxes because of the lack of parenthesis around the assignment, look at [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476759/compiler-warning-suggest-parentheses-around-assignment-used-as-truth-value) question for reference as to why you *should* have parenthesis around an assignment used as a *truth value*...

Also, there is something else that is also wrong with this program, consider this example:-

*For example:*

> ***What you actually wanted:-***
>
> > ABCD
> >     *< newline >*
>
> ***What you actually typed:-***
>
> > ABCD

And since the program didn't find the `'\n'` anywhere in the code, it leads to undefined behavior since it goes out of bounds to find it...

*There are two possible solutions when your input does not contain a `'\n'`:-*

- Use [`EOF`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) (Suggested by *many* since it the best possible solution for accepting every input...)

  ```
  int main() {
      char c;
      while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') /* Always remember to put parenthesis around
                                         an assignment in a condition... */
          putchar(c);
  }
  ```
- Add a newline to your input:-

  ```
  int main() {
      char c;
      // Use fputc to modify input...
      fputc('\n', stdin);
      while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') /* Always remember to put parenthesis around
                                         an assignment in a condition... */
          putchar(c);
  }
  ```

  *But, beware!* This method will stop *at the first iteration of newline it gets*, so if you have something outside of the `'\n'`, well it won't be printed...

Comment: The stuff about going out of bounds because of not seeing the `\n` is wrong. If the user never hits the carriage return, the program will block in `getchar()` If the user somehow does terminate the input stream without hitting return, `getchar()` will forevermore return `EOF`, which is not `\n` and the program will loop printing character `0xff` (assuming `EOF` is defined as `-1`).

Comment: The correct thing to do is define `c` as `int` and make the while loop `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')`